# Tableview presented modally and autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview

I have a problem with auto layout when I open a table view which is presented modally, in fact my current situation is the following:

[image: that's my current table view]

I'm developing an app using swift and I'd like to solve this problem with autolayout but currently I can't because it appears to be disabled.

[image]

Can somebody help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2).

Comment: Just select the table view first  and then pin tableview with these Constraints [Top,left,Right,bottom]

Answer (score 0):

From this screen click the dotted red line to select which constraint you want to add (top, bottom, leading, trailing)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not selected UI Element for which you want to set auto-layout constraint. Please select Label/Textfield and then add constraint as per your requirement. I hope this helps.